# DBT Macro using Sql and Jinja

Tags: sql, dbt

I have written the DBT macro and getting error when trying to deploy. I think it's not getting converted to proper sql.

`MoMCalc.sql`

```
{% macro MoMCalc(val,Effectivedate,Frequency) %}
case
when "Frequency" LIKE '%Weekly%' then {{val}} - LAG({{val}}, 4) OVER (Order by '{{Effectivedate}}')
when "Frequency" LIKE '%Monthly%' then {{val}} - LAG({{val}}, 1) OVER (Order by '{{Effectivedate}}')
end
{% endmacro %}
```

Error -

```
syntax error line 32 at position 0 unexpected 'case'.
20:33:23    syntax error line 33 at position 53 unexpected 'Value'.
20:33:23    syntax error line 33 at position 63 unexpected 'OVER'.
20:33:23    syntax error line 33 at position 88 unexpected 'Date'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can view the compiled code in the `target/compiled/` directory. (You'll want to look for the compiled version of the model file where you call this macro). That'll give you a sense for what went wrong.

I actually think you might just be missing a comma before you call the macro, in your model file?

My other guess (with limited context) is that you're not using curlies around the argument named `Frequency` in your macro. This should work, assuming you want double quotes *in the SQL* around the value passed into `Frequency`:

```
{% macro MoMCalc(val, Effectivedate, Frequency) %}
case
    when "{{ Frequency }}" like '%Weekly%'
    then {{ val }} - lag({{ val }}, 4) over (order by '{{Effectivedate}}')
    when "{{ Frequency }}" like '%Monthly%'
    then {{ val }} - lag({{ val }}, 1) over (order by '{{Effectivedate}}')
end
{% endmacro %}
```

Then to call that macro you want to use:

```
select
    another_field,
    MoMCalc('value_field', 'effective_date_field', 'frequency_field') as mom_calc
```